# Django CRSF across different origins for login request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-csrf

I have been struggling and doing research for couple of days. I am currently use Django with Django rest_framework and django-allauth to build backend APIs and the authentication workflow. Everything runs prefect by hosting everything onto the same origin VM(A).

Now due to requirement, I need to separate frontend login and backend API into two different origin. (A & B) APIs are behind the proxy.

Instead of using django-allauth default server rendered login page(which auto set the csrf in {% csrf_token %}) I have made a simple login.html and put it into host A under apache /var/www/html/:

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="https://B.com/accounts/login/">
  <input id="csrf" type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
  <p>
    <label for="id_login">Login:</label>
    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username or e-mail" autocomplete="email" required="" id="id_login">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password" required="" id="id_password">
  </p>
  <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
    // Get csrf from B and set into cookie 'getToken' API is defined below
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://B.com/getToken",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            $('#csrf').val(res.token);
            document.cookie = 'csrftoken=' + res.token;
        }
      })
    };
</script>
```

When the login.html is rendering it will make a GET request to the backend(B) API (/getToken) to fetch the csrftoken and save into the cookie and `csrfmiddlewaretoken` tag, when the login form is submitted csrftoken will be sent along with it.

and in the backend, I have installed `corsheaders`. and configured setting.py as following

```
from composed_configuration import ConfigMixin, ComposedConfiguration
from configurations import values


class Config(ConfigMixin):
  CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
  CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
  CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'https://A.com',
  )
  CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = values.ListValue(environ=True, default=['https://A.com'])
  @staticmethod
  def before_binding(configuration: ComposedConfiguration) -> None:
    configuration.REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'] += [
      'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ]
```

and to get csrf token I made an urls.py:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from django.urls import path

def getToken(request):
    token = get_token(request)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'token': token}), content_type="application/json,charset=utf-8")
path('getToken', getToken, name='getToken')
```

When I submit the form with username and password with csrf in the tag, I still get django `403 Forbidden error CSRF token missing or incorrect`.

Any idea, work around appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To someone who encountered the same issue, it is solved by adding `crossDomain: true` and `xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}` when get token in the frontend

In the backend add `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None`  `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None` option in the setting.py (by default the samesite is set to `lax`).